# IEEEtran: How to copy a snippet up without changing the cited number?

Tags: citing, ieeetran, copy-paste

I want to prevent the changing of the reference number when I duplicate a portion of the content.
The following code works when using the `plain` bibliography style, but I need to use the `IEEEtran` style.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Knuth1984texbook,
    Author = {Knuth, D.E.},
    Title = {The TEXbook, volume A of Computers and typesetting},
    Year = {1984}}

@book{Chomsky1957,
    Address = {The Hague},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {Mouton},
    Title = {Syntactic Structures},
    Year = {1957}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,conference]{IEEEtran}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\remembertext[2]{% #1 is a key, #2 is the text
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\unexpanded{\global\long\@namedef{mytext@#1}{#2}}}%
  #2%
}

\newcommand\recalltext[1]{%
  \ifcsname mytext@#1\endcsname
   \@nameuse{mytext@#1}%
  \else
    ``??''
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

The fragment copied, which must render [2] instead of [1]: 
\begin{quote}
``\recalltext{foo}''
\end{quote}

The first cite of the document: \cite{Chomsky1957}

The fragment with the second cite that I want to copy: \remembertext{foo}{Donald Knuth's \TeX book 
\cite{Knuth1984texbook}}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
% \bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that each use of `\cite` in your document writes a citation request to the `.aux` file. That is necessary, because BibTeX then gets the requested citations from the `.aux` file. In case the bibliography style sorts by citation order, that order can s calculated from the citation requests in the `.aux` file.

When you restate text from later in the document, the code still contains and thus executes `\cite` (at least normally, where `\cite` is a robust/unexpandable command), sending a citation request to the `.aux` file. This means that the citation may end up being sorted earlier than originally planned.

The code just appears to work for `plain`, because `plain` does not sort citations by appearance, but alphabetically. Hence, the order in which citations are mentioned in the text is irrelevant for sorting purposes.

We can exploit that the citation request is not written to the `.aux` file if we temporarily forbid writing to the `.aux` file with `\@fileswfalse`. So that's what we do in `\recalltext`. Note that then the citations only work since the citation request in `\remembertext` is generated as usual.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,conference]{IEEEtran}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\remembertext[2]{% #1 is a key, #2 is the text
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\unexpanded{\global\long\@namedef{mytext@#1}{#2}}}%
  #2%
}

\newcommand\recalltext[1]{%
  \ifcsname mytext@#1\endcsname
    \begingroup
    \@fileswfalse
    \@nameuse{mytext@#1}%
    \endgroup
  \else
    \G@refundefinedtrue
    ``\textbf{???}''
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Knuth1984texbook,
  Author = {Knuth, D.E.},
  Title  = {The TEXbook, volume A of Computers and typesetting},
  Year   = {1984},
}
@book{Chomsky1957,
  Address   = {The Hague},
  Author    = {Noam Chomsky},
  Publisher = {Mouton},
  Title     = {Syntactic Structures},
  Year      = {1957},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
The fragment copied, which must render [2] instead of [1]:
\begin{quote}
``\recalltext{foo}''
\end{quote}

The first cite of the document: \cite{Chomsky1957}

The fragment with the second cite that I want to copy:
\remembertext{foo}{Donald Knuth's \TeX book \cite{Knuth1984texbook}}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

> The fragment copied, which must render [2] instead of [1]:
> “Donald Knuth's TeXbook [2]”